# ReactJS: image src is not recognised properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am sending array of image sources from server (NodeJS Express) to client (ReactJS) and then i am mapping that array and adding each property to image as source

```
    {this.state.imageURLs.map((src, k)=>{
         return (
             <img src={src} key={k} alt="Hello" className="img"/>
         )
     })}
```

and here is log of ImageURLs in console:

> Array(1)
>   0: "/images/5c8a6e9567d7ad0a4ccf4e3c/bobi-1560108455536ae580d98-4916-4905-b3a0-5429e47f46ec144500.jpg"
>
> length: 1
>
> **proto**: Array(0)

and it displays alt (Hello). Why is that happening? Thanks!

**EDIT** here is how i am saving images into server (with multer) and how i am pushing them into array on server

```
const imgStorageBaseURL = '/images'
const imgStoragePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'images');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const userPath = path.join(imgStoragePath, req.userId);
    fs.mkdir(
      userPath,
      () => callback(null, userPath)
    )
  },


  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const filenameParts = file.originalname.split('.');
    const ext = filenameParts.pop();
    const basename = filenameParts.join('.');
    const additionalPath = Date.now() + '' + uuid() + '' + 
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    callback(null, basename + '-' + additionalPath + '.' + ext);
  },
})
```

and saving into array

```
var imgarray = []
req.files.forEach((file) => {
  imgarray.push(imgStorageBaseURL + '/' + req.userId + '/' + file.filename)
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct file path (from the location of the `<img>` tag)?

Comment: That's strange. Can you `console.log(src)` inside `map`?

Comment: @seelts i did and it logged same (mapped of course)

Comment: @YannickK check the edit please

Comment: @iLiA do you mean that you get *strings* like "/images/5c8a6e9567d7ad0a4ccf4e3c/bobi-1560108455536ae580d98-4916-4905-b3a0-5429e47f46ec144500.jpg"

 if you log src inside map?

Comment: @iLiA, just to be sure can also try `console.log(typeof src)`

Comment: if you visit `[approot]/images/5c8a6e9567d7ad0a4ccf4e3c/bobi-1560108455536ae580d98-4916-4905-b3a0-5429e47f46ec144500.jpg` directly, what happens?

Comment: @seelts yes i got strings like that

Comment: @WillJenkins i got nothing just a blank page

Comment: Did I get you correctly: in the element inspector you can only see `<img alt="Hello" className="img"/>` — without `src` attribute?

Comment: it seems like your problem might be how you're serving the images, in that case

Comment: @seelts no because of invalid img source it displays hello

Comment: but how? you can see the multer code

Comment: what is wrong with that then?

Comment: @iLiA can you please be more precise in your answers: if you look in the inspector, do you see `src` attribute there? I'm not asking about other attributes.

Comment: yes i see @seelts

Comment: Then the problem is not how it is generated inside `map`, it is what @WillJenkins says

Comment: convert your image into base64 and display in react js with the image src

Comment: when I visit [approot]/images/5c8a6e9567d7ad0a4ccf4e3c/bobi-1560108455536ae580d98-4916-4905-b3a0-5429e47f46ec144500.jpg as @WillJenkins said there is nothing and how it is supposed to be converted to base64?

Comment: You need to swap [approot] with whatever your environment is - probably http://localhost:3000 or similar

Comment: I know that LOL, i swapped